# Supremum of the Difference of Two Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Given two real-valued functions $f$ and $g$, is it true that $\sup(f-g) \geq \sup(f) - \sup(g)$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Copied from [this answer to a deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/244389):

> I think this question is asking how to show something like
> $$
> \sup_{x\in A}(f(x)+g(x))\le\sup_{x\in A}f(x)+\sup_{x\in A}g(x)\tag{1}
> $$
> This is an instance of the fact that the supremum over a set is no smaller than the supremum over a subset. The left hand side of $(1)$ is
> $$
> \sup_{\substack{x,y\in A\\x=y}}(f(x)+g(y))\tag{2}
> $$
> whereas the right hand side of $(1)$ is
> $$
> \sup_{x,y\in A}(f(x)+g(y))\tag{3}
> $$
> The set of $x$ and $y$ being considered in $(2)$ is a subset of the $x$ and $y$ being considered in $(3)$, so $(1)$ follows.

Using the result above, we have
$$
\sup((f-g)+g) \le \sup(f-g) + \sup(g)
$$
which becomes
$$
\sup(f-g)\ge\sup(f)-\sup(g)
$$

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: That answer was deleted when its question was. I have copied over the relevant part.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to add another answer which may provide some different intuition. We want to show
$$\mathrm{sup}(f-g)\ge\mathrm{sup}(f)-\mathrm{sup}(g).$$
To make everything in terms of addition we bring the minus sign inside the last supremum:
$$-\mathrm{sup}(g)=+\mathrm{inf}(-g).$$

If we now define $h(x)=-g(x)$, the problem them becomes to show
$$\mathrm{sup}(f+h)\ge\mathrm{sup}(f)+\mathrm{inf}(h).$$

This however is clear, since for all $x$ we have $h(x)\ge\mathrm{inf}(h)$, so
$$\mathrm{sup}(f+h)\ge\mathrm{sup}\left(f+\mathrm{inf}(h)\right)=\mathrm{sup}(f)+\mathrm{inf}(h).$$